# Fittonia Albivenis

Tags: houseplants, watering, sunlight

I bought this plant on 11/06/21, it has already started moving towards the sun, it is a north facing window.
I'm working on getting it a pebble tray soon, for the humidity, but I am confused on how damp the soil should be. There also seems to be this white powdery coating on the leaves.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the powdery coating come off on your fingers when you touch it?

Answer (score 1):

As a rule for potted plants always aim for less water, not more. The Fittonia Albivenis doesn't need direct sunlight, so just make sure the pot soil isn't too wet and give it enough exposure to indirect light. A North facing window seems like a good idea.

[Here](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/fittonia-albivenis/) is more info on how to take care of your Fittonia.